# how to add command buttons for Activate/deactivate and enable rule with custom javascript crm 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

In crm 2013 I am Created an Entity (Production) have 7 View to this view i need to Enable/Disable System Button ( Activate / Deactivate )Button
when am click selecting a record in Subgrid **Active Production** displaying 2 system button Activate/Deactivate.
but i need to display Deactivate Button and hide Activate the Button based on view

Examples:
1. inActive Production --- Activate Button Enable & Deactivate Button Disable

Please Give Some Suggestion and Examples

thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can use ribbon workbench [Download Ribbon Workbench](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/80806-download-ribbon-workbench-for-crm-2011-2013).

and apply a Enable Rule to your button that if production is inActive then button gets Enable and when production is Active button gets Disable.